# Magento controller redirect star notation

Tags: magento

Can someone explain the star slash notation used throughout magento controllers for redirecting?

The use by core code seems to be inconsistent and I cant find any decent docs out there that can explain the most correct use of this notation.

In the event that there is any doubt over what i am asking.

It is this style of redirect:

```
$this->_redirect('/');
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
$this->_redirect('*/*');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From left to right:

- frontname (associated with a router)
- controller
- action

When an asterisk is specified, it will use the -current- value of those above.

So assuming you are on `adminhtml/catalog/list` page, a redirect to `*/*/something` will take you to `adminhtml/catalog/something`, etc :)

Comment: I am probably just being a complete dummy here but are you saying that there will always only be a maximum of 3 values seperated by slashes.  The values can be asterix for current controller values or specified

Comment: Yes there will always be 3 (or less, since the last 2 will fallback to 'index' if not present). The controller one can have underscores, indicating deeper levels (filesystem) of controllers.

Comment: Something like adminhtml/catalog_foo_bar/hippy will point to a controller in the 'controllers/Catalog/Foo/Bar.php' file called BarController.

Comment: Above here I obviously meant NameSpace_ModuleName_Catalog_Foo_BarController :)